# Adding an automatic offset to the scroll position for all hash-links/calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, scroll, position

I have the following problem:

Like on Facebook, I have a menu bar at the top of the page that is always visible (`position: fixed;`). When I now click hash-links on my page (or load a new page with a hash in the url) to jump to a certain element on the page, the browser always scrolls this element to the very top of the page, meaning that the element is behind the top menu bar, afterwards.

I'd like to add some Javascript (jQuery or normal Javascript) that automatically adds a (negative) offset to this scroll position, so that the linked element is positioned right *under* the top menu bar when a link is clicked or the page is loaded. But I don't just want to add event listeners to all links that take care of this. I also want a solution that works, if the page is loaded with a hash portion in the url using the browser's address bar (or when linking to a different page with a hash at the end of the url).

Can you help me with this, please? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle to show?

Comment: How about add padding to the top of the element you're scrolling to?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Nowadays in 2021 there's a **nice simple only-css solution** with `:target` and `scroll-margin-top`

```
:target {
    scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}
```

It works [in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-margin-top)

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget

Comment: While the other suggestions prevent clicking on the content above the target, this solution works perfectly and looks like it's actually built for it.

Answer (score 32):

I actually found a solution myself that worked for me, using only css:

I added a `margin-top: -40px;` and `padding-top: 40px;` to the element that the jump-link was pointing to. This works for all major browsers: IE (7-9), Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Only problem: In case that this element is after a floated element, the negative margin doesn't work (meaning the positive padding becomes visible). Please comment, if anyone knows a solution/workaround for this. I'll update my post then. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it kinda moves the element "behind" the element(s) coming right before it and adds an inner "distance" (padding) to the top of the element. That way the browser thinks that the element's position is 40px "earlier" (nearer to the top of the page) than it's actual visible content is.

Comment: This works, the only issue I stumbled upon was that is you have absolutely positioned elements inside this element, you'd need to adjust it's positioning based on added padding.

Answer (score 8):

I found this way of adding a `:before` in the css seems to work well.

```
h2:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -285px; 
  height: 285px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

More at [CSS Tricks website](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/)

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me. I created a new class with these parameters and then applied a custom ID and this new class to the elements on my page and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the solution on this, I found that setting the display to none solved the issue of padding being visible when used amongst floated elements.

So:

```
.symbol-target {
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 1px; /* '0' will not work for Opera */
    display: none;
}
```

I also included this style as an empty div right above my target content.

Comment: `display: hidden` is not a thing

Answer (score 3):

```css
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   scroll-margin-top: 80px;
 }
```

Got this idea from React docs.

Answer (score 2):

As an example consider [D](http://dlang.org/)'s [bootDoc](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/bootDoc/) solution that works in all major browsers:

CSS (insert your titlebar height instead of `40px`):

```
.symbol-target {
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 1px; /* '0' will not work for Opera */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>
    <span class="symbol-target" id="myTarget">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#myTarget">My text</a>
</h3>
```

Real page example:

[`std.array.uninitializedArray` documentation using `bootDoc`](http://jakobovrum.github.com/bootdoc-phobos/std.array.html#uninitializedArray)

### Note:

It doesn't work for IE 6.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that worked best for me was to do this:

1. Give the designated ID (what you want in the URL) to a different element within the required element.
2. Make that new element absolute and move it X pixels above the required element, where X is the height of the fixed header.

Comment: This is my favorite. Nice, simple and feels less "hacky".

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else gave CSS answers but the question asked for JS

@assmmahmud's answer works with one small tweak: gotoSpecificPosition needs to changed to offsetAnchor in the first statement.

This was very helpful in adjusting all id links for a sticky header.

```
/* go to specific position if you load the page directly from address bar */
var navbarHeight = document.getElementById('mynavbar').clientHeight;
function offsetAnchor() {
  if (window.location.hash.length !== 0) {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - navbarHeight );
  }
}

/* Captures click events on all anchor tag with a hash tag */
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  // Click events are captured before hashchanges. Timeout
  // causes offsetAnchor to be called after the page jump.
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetAnchor();
  }, 0);
});

window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0);
```

Comment: My original question also states "But I don't just want to add event listeners to all links that take care of this.", but thank you for your extended solution, anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (at least using Firefox) neither padding nor margin helps here (putting them on a 'main' div containing everything but the menubar); scrolling to an anchor always puts it at the very top of the page, fixed elements be damned.

I think you're going to have to go with your original idea, but remember that by using delegation you can set just one handler that will work with all the links in your menubar, including ones dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript you can do the following. It will listen to a click event to all anchor tag and do scrolling to  your desired position in the page (It is using jquery):

```
/* go to specific position if you load the page directly from address bar */
var navbarHeight = document.getElementById('mynavbar').clientHeight;
function gotoSpecificPosition() {
  if (window.location.hash.length !== 0) {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - navbarHeight );
  }
}

/* Captures click events on all anchor tag with a hash tag */
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  // Click events are captured before hashchanges. Timeout
  // causes offsetAnchor to be called after the page jump.
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetAnchor();
  }, 0);
});

window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0);
```

The above code will handle all the tricks.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting a padding at the top of you page to occupy the area behind the menubar. Something like: `padding-top:80px;` (instead of 80px you should put the height of your menubar).

Comment: That didn't work. But I actually found a solution that worked for me using only css. I added a negative margin-top and a positive padding-top (same amount of pixels) to the element that the jump-link was pointing to. Only problem: In case that this element is after a floated element, the negative margin doesn't work (meaning the positive padding becomes visible). Do you have an idea for a workaround?