# anchor link position - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, anchor

i have a anchor on [this](http://ckoolhaas.buro210.com) website in the sidebar. When i click on the link it goes to the right page and the anchor also works but my menu is on top of the anchor so you can't see the title. How can i fix this so the user can see the title?

```
  <h3><a href="/Structuur-te-huur">Structuur te huur</a></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/Structuur-te-huur/#structuur-te-huur">Structuur te huur</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Structuur-te-huur/#procesbegeleiding">Procesbegeleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Structuur-te-huur/#projectmanagement">Projectmanagement</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Structuur-te-huur/#training">Training</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
#secondary .widget ul, #footer-widgets .widget ul{
    list-style-type: '- ';
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
#secondary .widget ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
}
#secondary .widget h3{
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}
/* widget paars*/
#secondary .widget:nth-child(2),
#secondary .widget:nth-child(7){
    background: #B167B3;
}
#secondary .widget:nth-child(2) h3,
#secondary .widget:nth-child(7) h3{
    background: #A263A4;
}
/* Oranje*/
#secondary .widget:nth-child(3){
    background: #FF9D29;
}
#secondary .widget:nth-child(3) h3{
    background: #FA9624;
}
/* Groen */
#secondary .widget:nth-child(4){
    background: #54D7C1;
}
#secondary .widget:nth-child(4) h3{
    background: #14C4A8;
}
/* Blauw */
#secondary .widget:nth-child(5){
    background: #63B9FC;
}
#secondary .widget:nth-child(5) h3{
    background: #36A6F6;
}
/* Rood */
#secondary .widget:nth-child(6){
    background: #F0524E;
}
#secondary .widget:nth-child(6) h3{
    background: #ED413A;
}
```

Comment: Mi no entender. I don't understand. Non comprend pas.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add your css. Did you tried to put link inside list?

Comment: i'm sorry but it is not on the home page. look [link](http://ckoolhaas.buro210.com/Structuur-te-huur/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add some top padding at the top of where you jump to, so that your menu does not cover it, or use javascript as in this question...
[Make anchor link go some pixels above where it's linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to)

If it doesn't harm your design too much, the padding is probably the best option - no need to add unnecessary javascript.

Comment: The padding and negative margin solution in the link there is probably going to be your best bet, as long as it doesn't create unclickable areas.

Comment: Thats probably the fix for now. but does it work for all the anchors? since the customer must be able to set anchors too.

Comment: That depends on how you code it, you can add it to all anchor links, or just to those with a class (in which case your customer woul have to add that class, or your CMS would have to do that for them).