# CSS make link to anchor go 100px lower

Tags: jquery, html, css

hello friends I have a link to an anchor in my html

```
<a href="#anchor">anchor</a>
```

And this goes to a div in my html

```
<div id="anchor" class="container-full">
</div>
```

My goals is to make it scroll a 100px lower, this is what I've tried with css but nothing happens, unfortunately.

```
#anchor{
    padding-top: -100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT added js**

```
jQuery(".nav li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $id = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
        jQuery("a.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        jQuery(this).addClass("clicked");
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: jQuery("#"+$id).offset().top
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Is that a typo? `href="#anchor"` won't go to `id="wie"`

Comment: @putvande ah yes I copied wrong div I edited OP

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Comment: Share the javascript piece of code that have the scrolling functionality. Modifying some pieces there you can solve easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make anchor link go some pixels above where it's linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I added my js to OP

Comment: My intention was provide you the same solution as @RionWilliams, so apply it, it's the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery to handle your scrolling, try adding 100 to your offset when setting your [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) property, which should cause your scrolling behavior to go 100px past the location of your target element in your [`animate()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjApozvkK_MAhVksoMKHejSAgIQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fanimate%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbtYj_CVrTF4Rx7m_-wysrfpbSQw&sig2=dLBtqotpjhU8_RrcQ7PVog&bvm=bv.120551593,d.amc) call :

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: jQuery("#"+$id).offset().top + 100 // scroll 100px past the element
}, 1000);
```

**Example Snippet**

```css
.space { height: 500px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#anchor" data-id='anchor'>anchor</a>
  <div class='space'></div>
  <div id="anchor" class="container-full"><h1>Hi</h1></div>
  <div class='space'></div>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("a.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#"+$id).offset().top + 100
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I use this jQuery for other elements on the same page is there a way I can apply it only on a specific anchor?

Comment: You could just change the jQuery selector to be more specific such as using a selector like `#id` to only select a specific element by its `id` attribute. Or if you wanted to only target elements that had the `data-id` attribute, you could use `$('[data-id']).click(...)`.