# scrolling to an element by id not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and trying to scroll a little past where an anchor link is supposed to link to after a hash change.

I have [made a codesandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/k853zrqkv)

[The answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to) should work but for some reason it isn't. Can anyone see where I may be going wrong? The `scrollToId` function does get called, but for some reason doesn't scroll to my desired location.

```
const Page = () => {

    let scrollToId = () => {

        if(location.hash.length !== 0) {

            window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 200);

        }

    }

    window.addEventListener("hashchange", scrollToId);

   return (
      <div>
          <a href="#one">Link</a>
          <p id="one">One</p>
      </div>
      );

}
```

Comment: What does your console show?

Comment: share some html or fiddler to demonstrate your issue!

Comment: I've tried your code in jsfidde, it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/85307/

Comment: @Andrew it scrolls alright, but it doesn't scroll the extra 200px

Comment: This "extra" 200px is all scroll height. You take your current scroll and plus 200px to this value. It's not an anchor.

Comment: @Andrew but my point is that it doesn't add this extra 200px

Comment: 200px to what value?

Comment: @andrew to the anchor that it gets scrolled to - see here https://codesandbox.io/s/k853zrqkv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153603/discussion-between-raul-rodriguez-and-andrew).

Comment: I've added you something that works like acnhor.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, thanks, that didn't work either for some reason. In the end I solved this using pure css

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct place to handle that. You need an event handler on your component in order to make it work. Otherwise you initialize the same `addEventListener` event multiple times on every `render` method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.handleScroll) // Initialize your listener
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('hashchange', this.handleScroll) // Remove your listener
  }

  handleScroll() {
    if (window.location.hash.length !== 0) {
      window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 200)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#one">Link</a>
        <p id="one">One</p>

        <div style={{ height: 900 }} />

        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: 600, height: 100 }}>
          Content
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't fix the issue

Comment: I've just updated the code sample. Please try again :)