# Single page anchor link goes bellow some pixels where it is linked with #link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

hi i am working on a single page website, issue i am facing right now is when i click on anchor of menu, it goes few pixels bellow the required area as shown in pic [image]

i want it like [image]

i have tried this code but no success
[Make anchor link go some pixels above where it's linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to)

Javascript i am using is

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Where is the source code to work with?

Comment: i am using a free html theme, which code you need brother ?

Comment: You should add the source code (HTML OR CSS) stating where the issue is......

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution of issue just by subtracting the desired height form the actual height.
Complete and running code for me is following

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var desiredHeight = $(window).height() - 577;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - desiredHeight
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```