# When scrolling to a specific section, I would like to move up by some pixels since the title gets hidden by the persistent header

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, href

I want to move to a specific section on click, and I am doing that using `<a name="updates"></a>` and `<a href="#updates">Updates</a>`. However, when I move to that section, the title of the section is not visible since it is hidden by the persistent header with `z-index: 99` (so it is always above all the other content). I would like to move a few pixels up so the title is visible when I click to move to that section.

I tried positioning the `<a name="updates"></a>` in a div that is rendered before the updates div, but that is not the proper solution, and makes the code confusing to read.

```
// Moving here
<a name="updates"></a>
...
// Link used to move there
<a href="#updates">Updates</a>
```

Comment: Can you add padding the target, enough to make it visible? For example: #updates { padding-top: 50px; }

Comment: Not really. I don't want to change the current structure/css of the page. So maybe a javascript solution?

Comment: How about this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to